# Elementary solution to a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt {x+1}\ln(x+1)-\sqrt{x}\ln (x)
$$

I tried to rearrange it for L'Hospital, but it gets even more complicated. It works when I write the Taylor expansion, etc... and the limit is $0$, but there must be an easier solution.

Comment: Maybe subtract and add $\sqrt{x+1}\ln x$ in the middle and treat each pair separately?

Comment: Use $f(x+1)-f(x)= f'(\xi)$ for some $x<\xi<x+1.$ You will see the limit is $0.$ No Hospital is needed.

Comment: Use the mean value theorem to show $$|\sqrt{x+1}\ln(x+1) - \sqrt{x}\ln(x)| \leq \frac{\ln(x+1)+2}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ and then apply L'Hopital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mean Value Theorem says that for continuous and differentiable function f, there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$

Or in this case, with $f(x) = \sqrt x\ln x$ there is a $c\in (x,x+1)$ such that $f'(c) = f(x+1)-f(x)$

If you find $\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {d}{dx} \sqrt x\ln x$ you can squeeze the limit you seek.

Comment: Called [*mean value theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).